# cmd git command runs git installer

Tags: windows, command-line, git

I used git for years now and recently after updating windows and git each time I type git commands in cmd window, it runs git installer.
git status ► runs git installer instead of showing the status
git ► runs git installer
I checked my PATH and everything looks normal
I checked registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\ and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\ and it looks completely normal.
I uninstalled git, rebooted and installed git again, rebooted and it still runs git installer.
I tried to run git from Powershell and admin Powershell, it still runs git installer.

What else should I do?

Comment: what is the output from running `where git`?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about 'where'! There was Heroku git file for some reason that is beyond me:
C:\Program Files\Heroku\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe
Removing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What else should I do?

Run `where git`. That will show you the errant version that is being executed.

Then modify your `PATH` to remove it.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [where](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html) - Locate and display files in a directory tree.